# Why console.log is not working in Atom in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

[Html file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTME8.png) [I just tried the simple Hello World in javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRwpa.png)

This is my atempt to show in the console a message using console.log.
I used Atom and I opened it in Chrome , I press inspect  , I go to console but there is no message.

Comment: Did you include the javascript file in the `index.html`?

Comment: No. I have a index.html and a index.js file

Comment: I added the javascript file as source in the html file.

Comment: You mean `<script src="index.js"></script>`?

Comment: It is working now. Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome! I summarized the conclusion in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If we create a `html` and a `javascript` file seperately, the `javascript` file has to be specified in the `html` as external `javascript` file. Therefore `<script src="index.js"></script>` has to be added to the `html` in the above example.

A complete code example can be found below.

The content of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World with JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>See the browser console for the console output.</p>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the `index.js`:

```
console.log("Hello World!")
```

As result we can see the `"Hello World!"` log message in the browser console, when the `html` page is loaded.

More details about using `javascript` with the `html` [can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp).